# What regex must I use?

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing an application in PHP, and I need to replace any word between `<!-- *` and `* -->` with it's correspondenting element in `$vars`.
For example,

```
<!-- *foobar* -->
```

In this case 'foobar' must be replaced by the variable `$vars["foobar"]`'s value. This is what I have now, but it does not work (it always returns `<>` :( ):

```
preg_replace_callback("<!--(\s+)\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*(\s+)-->", create_function('$matches', 'return $vars[$matches];'), $template);
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you match the spaces "(\s+)" as well as the actual word "([a-z...])" ? Shouldn't it just be "<!--\s+\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*\s+-->"?

Comment: @Dana: PHP gives me an error: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 6

Comment: Oh, and asterisks must be escaped :) too

Comment: I can see that I've left out the back-slash before the *. could that be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that you can't use $vars without introducing at with global keyword or by using $GLOBALS. Also if you're running PHP 5.3, you can use an anonymous function without an ugly global hack:

```
$template = preg_replace_callback('/<!--\s+\*(\w+)\*\s+-->/', function($matches) use ($vars) { return $vars[$matches[1]]; }, $template);
```

In pre-5.3 you can do this:

```
$template = preg_replace_callback('/<!--\s+\*(\w+)\*\s+-->/', create_function('$matches', 'return $GLOBALS["vars"][$matches[1]];'), $template);
```

If you don't run 5.3 but still want to avoid global variable, you can do this:

```
$template = preg_replace('/<!--\s+\*(\w+)\*\s+-->/e', '$vars["\1"]', $template);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
create_function('$matches', 'return $vars[$matches[2]];')
```

since the second group is the one you want. Not sure why you're capturing the others however. Also for this kind of thing I tend to prefer a global rather than calling `create_function()`.

Also, you're not delimiting the regex, like this version with /:

```
$vars = array(...);
preg_replace_callback('/<!--\s+\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*\s+-->/', 'replace_var', $template);

function replace_var($matches) {
  global $vars;
  return $vars[$matches[1]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is:

```
preg_replace_callback("/<!--\s+\*([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\*\s+-->/", create_function('$matches', 'return $vars[$matches[2]];'), $template);
```

The $matches variable is an array. Index 0 is what matched the whole regex and then any further indexes are the capture groups (if any) in the regex.

In this case $matches will look like this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(18) "<!-- *example* -->"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "example"
}
```